# ng-repeat dosent see data from outside ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I do not understand why ng-click above the loop can filter data and ng-click inside the first loop does not.

I totally don't know what is wrong

var booksAPP = angular.module('booksAPP',[]);

```
    booksAPP.controller('booksCTRL', function($scope) {
        $scope.bookData = {
            books: [
                {name: "JS learn", tag: "js", category: "javascript"},
                {name: "PHP learn", tag: "php", category: "php"},
                {name: "JS Ninja", tag: "js", category: "javascript"},
                {name: "HTML Ninja", tag: "html", category: "HTML"}
            ]
        };

        $scope.bookTAG = {
            tags: [
                {name: 'js'},
                {name: 'php'},
                {name: '.NET'},
                {name: 'HTML'}
            ]
        }

    })
```

```
<span ng-click="clickTAG = {'tag':'js'}">THIS WORKS NICE BEACUSE THEY BEFORE REPEAT</span>

<ul>
    <li><strong>TAGS:</strong></li>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in bookTAG.tags" ng-click="clickTAG = {'tag': tag.name}">{{tag.name}}</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><strong>BOOKS:</strong></li>
    <li ng-repeat="book in bookData.books | filter:clickTAG">{{book.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element generated by ng-repeat has its own scope, containing the additional `$index`, `$first`, etc. fields, as well as the `book` variable. So, if inside an ng-repeat you do

```
ng-click="clickTAG = {'tag': tag.name}"
```

you set a `clickTAG` field in the ng-repeated element's scope, instead of setting it to the controller scope.

To prevent this, and make your code cleaner at the same time, add the following function to the controller scope:

```
$scope.setClickTag = function(name) {
    $scope.clickTAG = {'tag': name};
}
```

and use

```
ng-click="setClickTag(tag.name)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ng-repeat creates its own scope and because of prototypical inheritance of `$scope` when you write `clickTAG = ...` it creates a new variable in `ng-repeat` scope. You can use `$parent` to refer to parents scope of `ng-repeat`:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>TAGS:</strong></li>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in bookTAG.tags" ng-click="$parent.clickTAG = {'tag': tag.name}">{{tag.name}}</li>
</ul>
```